# Create Route for a specific URL without changing the URL with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC Web Application that runs on `www.domain.com` and I need to configure a different URL binding for another domain `www.domain2.com` for the same web application.

The new domain `www.domain2.com` will have to return a specific Controller Action View like `/Category/Cars`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "www.domain2.com",
    url: "www.domain2.com",
    defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Cars", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

How can I achieve this without changing the URL, so the visitor inserts the url `www.domain2.com` and receives the view `www.domain.com/category/cars` but the url remains `www.domain2.com`?

EDIT:

I have tried this approach but it's not working:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Catchdomain2",
    "{www.domain2.com}",
    new { controller = "Category", action = "Cars" }
);
```

Comment: See [MVC Custom Routing Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35464970/), which is similar.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! It's not really easy to understand. I will have always a single case from www.domain2.com to www.domain.com/Category/Cars. Is there a more simple way to do that?

Comment: @NightOwl888 I have tried a different approach based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618896/asp-net-mvc-routing-how-do-i-match-the-whole-url/1618910#1618910 but it's not working :(

Answer (score 8):

Domains are normally **not** part of routes, which is why your examples don't work. To make routes that work **only on specific domains** you have to customize routing.

> By default, all of the routes in your route configuration will be available on **all domains** that can reach the web site.

The simplest solution for this is to create a [**custom route constraint**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) and use it to control the domains that a specific URL will match.

### DomainConstraint

```
    public class DomainConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private readonly string[] domains;

        public DomainConstraint(params string[] domains)
        {
            this.domains = domains ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(domains));
        }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            string domain =
#if DEBUG
                // A domain specified as a query parameter takes precedence 
                // over the hostname (in debug compile only).
                // This allows for testing without configuring IIS with a 
                // static IP or editing the local hosts file.
                httpContext.Request.QueryString["domain"]; 
#else
                null;
#endif
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
                domain = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];

            return domains.Contains(domain);
        }
    }
```

### Usage

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // This ignores Category/Cars for www.domain.com and www.foo.com
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Category/Cars", new { _ = new DomainConstraint("www.domain.com", "www.foo.com") });

        // Matches www.domain2.com/ and sends it to CategoryController.Cars
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HomePageDomain2",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Cars" },
            constraints: new { _ = new DomainConstraint("www.domain2.com") }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },

            // This constraint allows the route to work either 
            // on "www.domain.com" or "www.domain2.com" (excluding any other domain)
            constraints: new { _ = new DomainConstraint("www.domain.com", "www.domain2.com") }
        );
    }
}
```

If you fire this up in a new project in Visual Studio, you will notice it shows an error. This is because `localhost:<port>` is not a configured domain. However, if you navigate to:

```
/?domain=www.domain.com
```

You will see the home page.

> This is because for the debug build only, it allows you to override the "local" domain name for testing purposes. You *can* [configure your local IIS server](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/) to use a local static IP address (added to your network card) and add a local hosts file entry to test it locally *without the query string parameter*.
>
> Note that when doing a "Release" build, there is no way to test using a query string parameter, as that would open up a potential security vulnerability.

If you use the URL:

```
/?domain=www.domain2.com
```

it will run the `CategoryController.Cars` action method (if one exists).

Note that since the `Default` route covers a wide range of URLs, most of the site will be available to *both* `www.domain.com` and `www.domain2.com`. For example, you will be able to reach the About page both at:

```
/Home/About?domain=www.domain.com
/Home/About?domain=www.domain2.com
```

You can use the [`IgnoreRoute` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.ignoreroute(v=vs.118).aspx) to *block* URLs that you don't want (and it accepts route constraints, so this solution will work there, too).

This solution will work if you *largely want to share functionality* between domains. If you would rather have 2 domains in one web site, but make them act like separate web sites, it would be easier to manage if you use an [Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas) for each "web site" in your project by using the above route constraint for the Area routes.

```
public class Domain2AreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Domain2";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Domain2_default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
            constraints: new { _ = DomainConstraint("www.domain2.com") }
        );
    }
}
```

The above configuration would make *every URL* (that is 0, 1, 2, or 3 segments long) for `www.domain2.com` route to a controller in the `Domain2` Area.

Comment: Hi, thanks! In a performance point-of-view (I have been able to put @ArthNRick solution's running for my case), which solution works best? (yours or ArthNRick's)

Comment: From a performance point of view, they are roughly the same because ArthNRick's solution cascades the call to another action method rather than doing a redirect (which would issue a 302 response to the browser and tells it to lookup a new location on your server - extra network round trip). However, that solution won't scale well if you end up having more than a single view on `www.domain2.com`, and let's face it - that is probably going to happen. Routing is a separate concern than what goes on in an action method and domain names clearly fall into the scope of routing.

Comment: Also keep in mind, *all* URLs from `www.domain.com` will also be available on `www.domain2.com` (that is the default behavior). If that is what you intend, you should use a [Canonical Tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to tell search engines you meant to put the same content on 2 different URLs. If that is not what you intend, then use the `DomainConstraint` to block routes from the domains where you don't want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

in the default action of the application make sure that the url is the one of the second domain, then return the method that needs. something like:

```
      public ActionResult Index()
      {

        if (Request.Url.Host.Equals("domain2"))
            return AnotherAction();

      }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Would it not be better using a simple route? regarding also the analytics point of view.

Comment: I believe that this is not possible, what you need is an action redirection, since "domain.com" assumes the default route (usually "controller/action/{id}"), so on this default route you should correct location

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the answer above.

If you want more beautiful implementation - try action filters.
Sample of action filters usage from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute).

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var controller = (SomeControllerBase) filterContext.Controller;
    filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("index", "home");
}
```

Sample of getting the URL inside action filter from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761551/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-from-within-a-filterattribute).

```
var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
```

Put the things together and have fun :)

Comment: More beautiful implementation? this doesn't even provide an example of how to route a single action to two separate routes, and doesn't talk at all about the issue of redirects etc. This should be a comment.

Comment: @d_petrishin Please do not disregard the [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy of StackOverflow.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton dick is synonym to oath, what do you mean?

Comment: @d_petrishin Being a synonym does not make a word any more or less appropriate. You shouldn't call people names.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton but you do the same, why I shouldn't?

Comment: @d_petrishin When did I call someone a name?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton now, mine?

Comment: @d_petrishin Remember answers can move up and down and to different pages. Why not use a link to the answer? Just click on `share` to get one.