# Asp.net MVC multiple web projects in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, multi-project

I have a solution having two MVC Web Projects.

In main project, **AdminController** is works as expected(When I hit Admin/Action it looks for view in main project and work accordingly).

In second project I have **SiteController**. When I hit Site/Action it looks for view in main project and as it is not available in main project and throw error.

I want to access second project controller through main project but don't know how to achieve this.

I do not want to use Area functionality in main project. **SiteController** should be in second project and should be accessible through main project.

Comment: Did you start both the projects. if yes both have different ports.so hit the appropriate port.

Comment: Thank you @AvinashReddy for your response.


I have started both the project and I can access Site controller through second project port but I want to access SiteController using main project port.


I am accessing AdminController through 'http://localhost:port1/Admin/action' so I want to access SiteController through main project port that is port1  'http://localhost:port1/Site/action'.

I can easily access SiteController though port2 but url should be 'http://localhost:port1/Site/action'.

Hope I am able to clear my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Route for a specific URL without changing the URL with MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542759/create-route-for-a-specific-url-without-changing-the-url-with-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions for this:

1. Include the controllers of project 2 in project 1. This is not the same as an area but you'll have to add a reference to project 2 in project 1. [asp-net-mvc-6-discovers-controllers](https://www.strathweb.com/2015/04/asp-net-mvc-6-discovers-controllers/)
2. If 1 is not an option, then you can debug directly on your local IIS without ports **BUT** on different site names. This makes sense as the **ARE** different sites. If they aren't then they should be hosted on the same project (see 1st solution).

- Go to project properties
- Select Web
- On the Servers section choose local iis
- Set the project url

[image]